# Can the inequality below be satisfied for an imputation $\mathbf{x}\in\mathcal{PK}(N,\nu)$?

Tags: game-theory

Consider any $0$-monotonic TU game $[N,\nu]$.

> A game $[N,\nu]$ is $0$-monotonic if $\nu(L\cup\{i\})\geqslant\nu(L)+\nu(\{i\})$ for all Players $i\in N$ and all coalitions $L\subseteq N\backslash\{i\}$.

Further, consider the Kernel of such a game, denoted $\mathcal{K}(N,\nu)$. By [Maschler, Peleg & Shapley (1971)](http://www.dtic.mil/dtic/tr/fulltext/u2/732666.pdf), the Kernel and the Prekernel, denoted $\mathcal{PK}(N,\nu)$, coincide whenever $[N,\nu]$ is $0$-monotonic.

> The Prekernel is defined as the set of vectors $\mathbf{x}\in\mathbb{R}^N$ that satisfy $\sum_{i\in N}x_i=\nu(N)$ and
>   \begin{gather*}
> \max_{S\subseteq N}\left\{\nu(S)-\sum_{k\in S}x_k\mid i\in S,j\notin S\right\}=\max_{S^{\prime}\subseteq N}\left\{\nu(S^{\prime})-\sum_{k\in S^{\prime}}x_k\mid j\in S^{\prime},i\notin S^{\prime}\right\}
> \end{gather*}

Let me now phrase my question: given a $0$-monotonic game $[N,\nu]$, **is it possible to find a vector $\mathbf{x}\in\mathcal{K}(N,\nu)$ and a pair of Players $i,j\in N$ for whom the inequality below is satisfied?**
\begin{gather}\label{eq1}
\nu(N)-\sum_{k\in N\backslash\{i,j\}}x_k<\max_{S\subseteq N\backslash\{i,j\}}\left\{\nu(\{i\}\cup S)-\sum_{k\in S}x_k\right\}+\max_{S^{\prime}\subseteq N\backslash\{i,j\}}\left\{\nu(\{j\}\cup S^{\prime})-\sum_{k\in S^{\prime}}x_k\right\}
\end{gather}

Either provide an example showing that it is possible, or provide a solid argument showing it is not possible.

Thank you all very much in advanced for your time.

**EDIT**: following the first comment, I provide here some background. I am basically studying the set of SPE outcomes of a bargaining game. So far, I have been able to prove that the if $\mathbf{x}\notin\mathcal{PK}(N,\nu)$, then $\mathbf{x}$ is not a SPE outcome. However, I am still not sure for which family of games $[N,\nu]$ a SPE exists, nor which Prekernel elements can be sustained as an SPE. I know that if $\mathbf{x}$ satisfies the above inequality, then $\mathbf{x}$ is not a SPE outcome. Thus, I was curious to know if such an inequality could be satisfied for some $0$-monotonic game $[N,\nu]$ and some $\mathbf{x}\in\mathcal{PK}(N,\nu)$.

Comment: Can you give some hints where this condition is coming from? Can you even provide some intuition related to this condition? That is to say, what is its meaning?

Comment: Following your request, I have edited my question. I hope the clarification helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us consider the following six-person weighted majority game that we obtain from the following parameters:

$$[16;2,4,4,5,6,7],$$

which we have borrowed from Kopelowitz (1967). This game has a disconnected pre-kernel given by the two points

$$\mathcal{PK}(N,v)=\{\{0,0,0,0,1,1\}/2,\{0,1,1,1,1,1\}/5\}.$$

Notice, that this game is zero-monotonic and has an empty core. If we now select the second point of the pre-kernel solution, we get the following matrix of maximum surpluses

```
     0    0.4000    0.4000    0.4000    0.4000    0.4000
0.4000         0    0.4000    0.4000    0.4000    0.4000
0.4000    0.4000         0    0.4000    0.4000    0.4000
0.4000    0.4000    0.4000         0    0.4000    0.4000
0.4000    0.4000    0.4000    0.4000         0    0.4000
0.4000    0.4000    0.4000    0.4000    0.4000         0
```

Let us denote this matrix as $smat$. Similar, we get a matrix of surpluses over efficiency for all coalitions of $N\backslash \{i,j\}$ with $i,j \in N, i \neq j$, which is quantified through

```
     0    0.2000    0.2000    0.2000    0.2000    0.2000
0.2000         0    0.4000    0.4000    0.4000    0.4000
0.2000    0.4000         0    0.4000    0.4000    0.4000
0.2000    0.4000    0.4000         0    0.4000    0.4000
0.2000    0.4000    0.4000    0.4000         0    0.4000
0.2000    0.4000    0.4000    0.4000    0.4000         0
```

and denoting this matrix as $B$. Set then $A=smat+smat'$ and take the difference $A-B$, and we observe that the above condition is satisfied through

```
     0    0.6000    0.6000    0.6000    0.6000    0.6000
0.6000         0    0.4000    0.4000    0.4000    0.4000
0.6000    0.4000         0    0.4000    0.4000    0.4000
0.6000    0.4000    0.4000         0    0.4000    0.4000
0.6000    0.4000    0.4000    0.4000         0    0.4000
0.6000    0.4000    0.4000    0.4000    0.4000         0
```

**Update: Weighted Majority Game:**

To avoid to supply the whole game with $64$ coalitions, I just concentrate on the definition of a weighted  majority game, and giving a short explanation of it.

Let the total number of votes are denoted as $w(N) \in \mathbb{N}$. For passing a bill at least $0 < th \le w(N)$ votes are needed. A simple game is referred to a weighted majority game, if there exists a quota/threshold $ th > 0$ and weights $w_{k} \ge 0$ for all $k \in N$ such that for all $S \subseteq N$ it holds either $v(S) = 1$ if $w(S)  \ge th$ or $v(S) = 0$ otherwise. Such a game is generically represented as $[th; w_{1}, \ldots, w_{n}]$.

I hope this clarifies your question.

Comment: Today, while re-reading your question, I realised that I am not sure I understand correctly the representation of your six-person weighted majority game. Could you please write the characteristic function in the usual lexicographic order or, else, provide some help on how to construct it out of those parameters? Thank you very much.